# Overloading addition in an abstract class

Tags: python, abstract-class

I was trying to figure out how to overload the `__add__` method in python for an abstract class, but was unable to. Here is the problem I am trying to solve:

```
import numpy as np 
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class RandomVariable(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def sample(self):
        pass
    
    # I want to override the __add__ method 
    # to return a random variable
    # such that the sample method is the addition from 
    # left.sample() and right.sample()
    
class NormalVariable(RandomVariable):
    def __init__(self, mu=0, sigma=1):
        self.mu = mu
        self.sigma = sigma
    def sample(self):
        return np.random.normal(self.mu, self.sigma)

class ExponentialVariable(RandomVariable):
    def __init__(self, scale=1):
        self.scale=scale
    def sample(self):
        return np.random.exponential(self.scale)
```

That is, I want to be able to do something like `my_random_variable = NormalVariable() + ExponentialVariable()`.

**Edit**

Is this the standard way of solving it:

```
import numpy as np 
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod



class RandomVariable(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def sample(self):
        pass
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        return AddedVariable(left=self, right=other)
    
    
class NormalVariable(RandomVariable):
    def __init__(self, mu=0, sigma=1):
        self.mu = mu
        self.sigma = sigma
    def sample(self):
        return np.random.normal(self.mu, self.sigma)

class ExponentialVariable(RandomVariable):
    def __init__(self, scale=1):
        self.scale=scale
    def sample(self):
        return np.random.exponential(self.scale)
    
    
class AddedVariable(RandomVariable):
    def __init__(self, left, right):
        self.left = left 
        self.right = right
    def sample(self):
        return self.left.sample() + self.right.sample()
```

Comment: You should try to implement `__add__()` in the base class.

Comment: Yes, thats what I would like to do, but dont know how.

Comment: You can have the default implement `return NotImplemented` — see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#NotImplemented).

Comment: You seem to have been able to implement various methods already. What is the problem with `__add__()`?

Comment: See new edit -- is that the standard way? I would like to overload all the operators `*, -, **`, does that mean that i need classes `SubstractedVariable`, etc?

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you want these operators to build an expression tree which dynamically generates numbers for each leaf variable. So I think that's how I'd do it. Maybe you should submit this to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?